# Lotus Notes 8.5: Show count of read and unread messages of a folder

Tags: lotus-notes

is it possible to show the count of read and unread messages in the left folder view?

For example, the left folder view should show: MyFolder (5/15)

The count means, in the folder MyFolder are 5 unread messages and 15 read messages.

I'm a roookie in programming witht Lotus Notes and hope somewhere has a good idea.

Greetings from Germany

Rainer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of unread documents in a view/folder with

```
unread = view.GetAllUnreadEntries().Count
```

and the total number of documents in view with

```
total = view.EntryCount
```

Comment: Hello Knut,

THX for answering!
And how to place the text "(5/15)"  after the Folder-Name?
Which object or whic Event is the right place?

Kind regards 

Rainer :)

Comment: You can create a Page or a Form (with SaveOptions="0") for Navigation, calculate the "(5/15)" in LotusScript, recalculate it regularly based on view-clicks or timer and show it in a computed text or field. It is definitely tricky and not really a task for a Notes development beginner... It will have some performance issue too if the view has a lot of entries.

Comment: Thanks Knut, I was so used to this ad and Notes is here a little stiff.